# Lambert W function implementation in Java

Tags: java, math, numerical-analysis

I'm working on a project and have found myself in a situation where I need a function to be able to get at least an approximation of the value of W(x), the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), where x can be any real number.  I'm working in Java.  I couldn't find any implementations of W in java when I searched.  I am willing to code up the implementation myself if need be, but I am unsure of how that would be done right now.  Any pushes in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, if it makes a difference, I think that I only need W on the domain of [0,inf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

It lists an approximation for `z>3` as well as a series expansion for the function.

You can also use Newton's method and Halley's method to approximate the function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation

Comment: Looking at the approximation for z>3 on the first link you posted, I understand most of the formula except for the end bit.  What does the O[(L1/L2)^6] part mean?  Also when it says something like L2(-2 + L2) would that be lnlnz * (-2 + lnlnz) or lnln(-2 + lnlnz)?

Comment: The `+O(stuff)` at the end is just an error term. You can ignore it. And `L2(-2 + L2) = lnlnz * (-2 + lnlnz)`

Comment: Thanks! That clears some things up.  So I could probably just use that formula for input to the function greater than 3, and find a simpler approximation formula for input between 0 and 3?

Comment: That sounds about right. You should compare all these different methods though to see which one gives you the best approximation. I don't know the answer to that question.

Answer (score 3):

The lambert function is the reciprocal function of `g(w) = w*exp(w)` it verifies:

```
W(z)eW(z) = z.
```

A good way to evaluate W(z) on a given z would be to use [newton raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) method :

to solve : `f(Y)= Yexp(Y) - z = 0.`

you will find `Y = W(z)` with the method

You would have to find and implementation in java of the method yourself.

Hope it helps

below an illustration from wikipedia of the method:

[image]